# How to implement dropdown and also clickable using JavaScript or CSS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a dropdown which is clickable also. Like I have a menu which has dropdown options so If I hover on it, will display dropdown and if I want to click on that, it should display link that has been provided to it.

This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="mainservice.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> Logistics Services </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ftl.html">FTL</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ltl.html">LTL</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="intermodal.html">Intermodal</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, now I want that if I click on **Logistics Services** then mainservice.html page should display and dropdown should also be there. It should be mobile friendly also.

I tried through CSS, but when I checked it on mobile, then it is not working as expected.

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover div.dropdown-menu{
    display:block;
}
```

**How should I do it?**

[image: Screenshot to display dropdown]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use <ul> list instead of <select> dropdown for the languages switcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926368/how-can-i-use-ul-list-instead-of-select-dropdown-for-the-languages-switcher)

Comment: "when I checked it on mobile, then it is not working as expected", because there's no `:hover` on mobile

Comment: @GrafiCode So is there any other way to get it done on both the devices?

Comment: You can't have the drop down toggle as a link otherwise how will it know when to open the drop down or when to navigate off to the page, it can only do either one or the other.  If you are saying you want to navigate off to the page and then open the dropdown, then that is very poor ux

Comment: I have seen somewhere, and that was built in wordpress. So yes, there it was working. I don't know how.

Comment: It would most likely have been a hover menu

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549436/3807365

Comment: this answer makes use of `:active` in combination with `:hover` to handle desktop / mobile interactions https://stackoverflow.com/a/22560108/5334486